# accessing div tag attributes in css to make elements invisible

Tags: html, css

for the html tag

```
<div class="test" label= "hello" second-label="world"/>
```

I'm trying to access the label and second-label attribute, but I don't know if my css is wrong or I'm not doing it properly.

```
.test[label="hello"] {
     visibility: hidden;
}
```

this doesn't seem to be doing anything. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: With custom data attributes available (`data-`) you shouldn't be making up your own attribute syntax. Also, divs can't be self-closing.

Answer (score 0):

`div` elements aren't self close:

```css
.test[second-label="world"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" label="hello" second-label="world">test</div>
```

Despite this it works as it should.

edit:

You can use data- instead as @j08691 mention in his comment. [custom data attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2A-attributes)

So in your example you can use:

```css
.test[data-secondLabel="world"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" label="hello" data-secondLabel="world">test</div>
```

Comment: does not solve the issue, I still can't access the attribute

Comment: Check updated answer. You can use `data-` instead as @j08691 mention in his comment.